# Expressions similar to "I would give my right arm"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

How can one idiomatically say in French something similar to

> I would give my right arm to...

Does an one to one literal translation make sense?

In a similar vein, in the film [Edward Scissorhands](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/27915) one actor says

> I'd give my left nut to see that again.

How this sentence could be rendered in French?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela dépend beaucoup de ce à quoi le locuteur tient le plus, de ce qui présente le plus de **valeur** à ses yeux...

Des rois (Richard III) donneraient leur royaume, Cléopâtre aurait donné son sceptre, un duc de Verdi sa couronne...

Moins royal mais peut-être plus héroique, on peut donner son épée...

J'ai aussi vu passer quelqu'un qui aurait donné son chapeau, un mathématicien qui aurait donné rien moins que sa vie ainsi qu'un lexicographe qui aurait donné un mot...

Après... quand on est moins nanti... c'est plus dur évidemment... alors ne resteront plus que *sa dernière chemise, son dernier sou...*

... pathétique!

Donc, tu vois, cela dépend beaucoup du contexte et du personnage ainsi que... du caractère qu'on cherche à lui donner et selon que l'on veut faire tragique ou comique. À cette fin, ce genre de formule, en ce qu'elle hiérarchise des *valeurs*, est particulièrement éloquent. (Je pense à ta seconde phrase)

**EDIT :** Et, quand j'y songe... on n'est évidemment pas obligé de donner un truc à soi non plus hein... Cela communique un certain genre aussi que de donner... ce qui, de toute évidence, ne vous appartient pas... 
Ainsi, par exemple... voyons voir...

J'aurais bien donné ta thèse de doctorat contre un verre de single malt!

Comment: San-Antonio s'était fait le spécialiste de donner, proposer en échange ou parier des choses des autres.

Comment: Dès le premier tome, par exemple: «Quand je pense que le monde est plein de zigotos qui sont, à la même minute, en train de se faire des cocottes en papier dans les ministères, de pêcher sur les bords de la Marne ou bien d'expliquer à des chouettes poupées ce que le créateur avait derrière la tête lorsqu'il a conçu et réalisé les dames et les messieurs, je me sens plein de vague à l'âme. Et je donnerais bien dix ans de la vie du président Truman contre une vieille paire de fixe-chaussettes pour être un de ces types dont je vous parle.»

Comment: Bof, aucune des expressions que tu cites ne me paraissent particulièrement idiomatique.

Comment: @Gilles : Qu'entends-tu par là ? Que nous n'avons pas les mêmes références ? Oui! Ça j'avais déjà noté. Mais ce n'est pas grave. Je découvre maintenant que nous ne suivons pas non plus la même grammaire... c'est plus gênant ça.

Answer (score 6):

There is an equivalent phrase, albeit maybe a bit more violent in the image it conveys:
*tuer père et mère pour quelque chose* (always used with the verb in the conditional form).

> Je tuerais père et mère pour avoir une Porsche !
>
> Il serait prêt à tuer père et mère pour devenir célèbre.

Comment: Oui c'est vrai et il est aussi très éloquent. Tellement que je ne l'ai jamais vu conjugué à la première personne.

Comment: Et la version plus douce: VENDRE père et mère.

Answer (score 2):

Those are basic translations;

> [je donnerais cher pour ; je donnerais n'importe quoi pour](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/I%27d+give+my+right+arm+for)

On peut aussi dire « je donnerai beaucoup pour ».

Voilà ce que l'on [trouve pour « [I'd give my left nut to](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131126121517AAjaiNO) »;

> The seminal vessicle in the left testicle is the primary distributor of sypmathetic nerve endings. It houses the orbicular retensor which allows you to have pleasurable sensations during sexual intercourse and manual stimulation. So, of course, when a man offers his "left nut" he is basically saying "I'd give up orgasming for the rest of my life for that." It's a colloquial expression most often used by fray boys and miscreants.

Il faut donc traduire par « je donnerai mon testicule gauche pour » ou si on veut vraiment l'authenticité du registre  d'origine, par la même chose en remplaçant « testicule » par le candidat consacré (couille).

If that is acceptable in the Anglo-Saxon world -- the above comments show it's far from being universally so --, it's certainly not considered as showing good taste in most places in France, whatever the reasons for that and whatever alternative term is being used.